# how to use 'IN' clause in linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public static List<mainISRC> comedianlist(int iid)
{
     List<mainISRC> newlst = new List<mainISRC>();
     ISRCManagementDBEntities1 dbcontext = new ISRCManagementDBEntities1();
     newlst=(from z in dbcontext.Comedians
             where !(from b in dbcontext.mainISRCs 
             where b.id==iid && b.Actor1==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian1==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian3==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian4==z.Comedian1).Any()
             select z.Comedian1).ToList();            
     return newlst;
}
```

I have a table name "comedian" with column 'id','Comedian' and 'IsActive' which contain 50 numbers of rows and also I have another table name "mainISRC" with column 'id','Actor1','Actor2','Actor3','Actor4'. 'id' column in "actorlist" and 'iid' column in "addrecord" are not same.

I have to find all those 'comedian' from "comedian" which are not in 'Actor1','Actor2','Actor3','Actor4' column. What will be the Linq query for this?

Comment: [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final Update Code

Sorry code is not tested but it may help you or gives you a direction

```
  List<int> liComedianId = new List<int> ();
liComedianId = dbcontext.Comedians.Select(s => (int)s.Id).ToList();

List<mainISRC> limainISRC = new List<mainISRC> ();
limainISRC = dbcontext.mainISRCs.ToList();

var d = ((from a in limainISRC.Select(s => s.Actor1).ToList()
select a).TolList().Union
            (from b inlimainISRC.Select(s => s.Actorb).ToList()
select b).Tolist()).ToList();
d = d.Distinct();

licomedianId =  licomedianId.Select(s => !d.Contain(s));

List<comedian> LIcomedianFinal = new List<comedian> ();
LIcomedianFinal =  dbcontext.Comedians.ToList();
var FinalList =(from a in  LIcomedianFinal .ToList()
                join b in d.TolIst()
                on a.Id equlas d).ToList();
```

Comment: this code is not working sir. Please help me sir..

Comment: try it with && operator

Comment: yes sir.. I have modified your code as       List<Comedian> liComedian = new List<Comedian>();
            liComedian = dbcontext.Comedians.ToList();

            List<mainISRC> limainISRC = new List<mainISRC>();
            limainISRC = (from z in dbcontext.mainISRCs where z.id == iid select z).ToList();

            var FilteredList = limainISRC.Where(w => !liComedian.Contains(w.Actor1) || !liComedian.Contains(w.Actor2) || !liComedian.Contains(w.Actor3)).ToList();

Comment: is there any error you got or you're not getting correct output

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ISRCMANAGER.Models.Comedian>.Contains(ISRCMANAGER.Models.Comedian)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: sir this is the code I have update but it is showing same error what I have explained above..    List<Comedian> liComedian = new List<Comedian>();
            liComedian = dbcontext.Comedians.ToList();

            List<mainISRC> limainISRC = new List<mainISRC>();
            limainISRC = (from z in dbcontext.mainISRCs where z.id == iid select z).ToList();

            var FilteredList = limainISRC.Where(w => !liComedian.Contains(w.Comedian1) || !liComedian.Contains(w.Comedian2) || !liComedian.Contains(w.Comedian3) || !liComedian.Contains(w.Comedian4)).ToList();

Comment: try my new updated code.. in your code you were comparing liComedian.Contains(w.Comedian1) where  liComedian is List of type Comedian .. thus the error you got is becoz of you are comparing an object of class with an int type comedian1 .. thus change the type of your Licomedian to List<int> and then you compare it

Comment: @user3270379 did you got what is said

Comment: This is my update query. Please take it carefully ..... I have to find all those comedian from Comedian table whose  are not in mainISRC table with column name 'Comedian1','Comedian2','Comedian3','Comedian4'. Below I have paste my code which currently have no any error but I am not getting required record from Comedian table..

Comment: ISRCManagementDBEntities1 dbcontext = new ISRCManagementDBEntities1();
            List<string> liComedianId = new List<string>();
            liComedianId = dbcontext.Comedians.Select(s=>s.Comedian1).ToList();

            List<mainISRC> limainISRC = new List<mainISRC>();
            limainISRC = dbcontext.mainISRCs.Where(x=> x.id==iid).ToList();

            var FilteredList = limainISRC.Where(w => !liComedianId.Contains(w.Comedian1) || !liComedianId.Contains(w.Comedian2) || !liComedianId.Contains(w.Comedian3) || !liComedianId.Contains(w.Comedian4)).ToList();

Comment: what should i do with this code

Comment: I have to find all those comedian from Comedian table whose are not in mainISRC table with column name 'Comedian1','Comedian2','Comedian3','Comedian4'.  This is the result I want to find from this code. Please help me sir.... its too urgent for me..